# Combine jQuery Mosaic with CSS3 box-shadow page curl effect

Tags: jquery, css, gallery, mosaic

i would like to combine this two effects

jQuery Mosaic > http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/
and
Pure CSS3 box-shadow page curl effect > http://matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html

Can somebody provide me an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward.  I simply placed the "Mosaic Div" (The Div that was containing the mosaic tile) inside of the `li` of my curling box shadow `ul`.  Pretty straight forward.

```
<ul class="box">
    <li>
        <div class="mosaic-block circle">
            <a href="http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic" class="mosaic-overlay">&nbsp;</a>
            <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/mosaic.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```